# NetworkOnMainThreadException Error in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, networking

i'm trying to do use a JSOUP HTML parsing library to get a HTML document using

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(u, 1000);
```

and i'm getting the error `"android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"`

I understand its because I need to have the download occurring somewhere other than the main thread but I don't understand how to fix this.

If I use threading I need to be able to return `doc` so I can parse through when the download is finished.

Can you help me fix this?

The class I am using is as follows:

```
public class DataSorter{

   private Document doc;
   DataSorter(){
      downloadData();
   }
   private void downloadData() throws IOException{
        String url = "www.google.com";
        URL u = new URL(url);
        System.out.println("Downloading....");
        doc = Jsoup.parse(u, 5000); //Time out 5000ms
        System.out.println("Download Successful");
   }
   Document getDoc(){
      return doc;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a Network Related operation on the main ui thread. use a `Thread` or `AsyncTask`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

AsyncTask docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

A similar post @

[How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

You can use a `Thread` but remember you can update ui on the ui thread and not on the background thread.

You can use AsyncTask use `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` to update ui. Use `doInbackground` to do your network related operaion.

Move this

```
   Document doc = Jsoup.parse(u, 1000);
```

inside a `Thread` or `doInbackground` of AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2):

use an asynctask and return the doc to the onPostExecute

see this link about an asynctask

[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Answer (score 1):

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

because you are performing `network operations in main UI thread`

ether use `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`

reference for AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html